# use variable from another class

Tags: java, class, variables

I have two classes. I want to use `english` and `french` from the first class in the second class (class Question). Please help me to fix that code because it shows me an error.

Code Blocks :

```
package josephtraduire;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileParser implements IParser{

    @Override
    public void parseFile () throws IOException{
        String french="";
        String english="";

        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text.txt"))){
            String line;        
            while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                    String[] pair = line.split(";");
                    french=(pair[0]);
                    english=(pair[1]);
            }
        }        
    }            

}
```

and

```
package josephtraduire;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question extends FileParser {

String mot ;
String reponse ;
String name;
int nb;
int nbquest ;
String traduction;

Question (String name , int nb){
    this.name=name;
    this.nb=nb;
}

Question() throws IOException{

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr); 
    { 
        System.out.println("Entrer votre nom "); 
        String nom = in.readLine(); 
        name=nom;
    }    

    do {
        System.out.println("Rentrez le nombre de question :    ( max 20 )");
        Scanner nombrequest = new Scanner(System.in);
        nbquest = nombrequest.nextInt();
        nb=nbquest;
    }  while ( nbquest>20 ||nbquest<=0);

}

public void Play () throws IOException{

    int i=0;   
    boolean bool=true;    
    int score=0;
    String continuer; 
    Date maDate = new Date();
    String a = maDate.toString() ;

    while (i<nbquest && bool) {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr); 

        System.out.println("donner la traduction de "+french);
        String reponseee  = in.readLine();     
        traduction=reponseee;  

        if(bool=true ){ 
            if(traduction.equals(english)){
                score++;
                System.out.println("Bravo! Bonne reponse");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Mauvaise reponse");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please format your code and post only relevant code snippet.

Comment: ... your ... your coding formatting ... the horror ....

Comment: Please format your code one more time and delete all unnecessary whitespaces, etc...

Comment: first of all format your code by using : ctrl+a and ctrl +shift+f (if you are using eclipse..)

Comment: My eyes are going to explode

Comment: @LukasWarsitz - format one more time???

Comment: What is `***french***=(pair[0]);` and `***english***=(pair[1]);`? Some kind of never seen Java pointers? O_O

Comment: You really need to pick up a beginner's book, or read a tutorial. Don't rush it.

Comment: R.I.P Indentation and formation :_____(

Comment: Besides the awful formatting of the question there is so much wrong with this "implementation" that I do not even know where to begin. General naming conventions also seem to be thrown out the window when there's something like `public void Play ()` Execution seems to be within a constructor and there is no main method or anything in sight.

Comment: Why is it still horrible after about 3 edits?

Comment: You misspelled _french_ twice in your question, but not in your code. Did you write this?

Comment: I don't believe any amount of edits will save this train-wreck

Comment: I'm struggling to get a full grasp of this, but 2 points. `English` and `French` are not instance members of the first class, they are just variables in a method. They are like mayflies, they live for but the scope of the method and then are gone. And what is `***french***=(pair[0]);`, I have never see the `***` operator before

Comment: *** is probably OPs attempt at bold text

Comment: @ all wannabe editors: if you're too lazy to do it properly, please leave it to others

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore the source code and answer this in general terms. You can access the instance variables of an object, either directly or using getters. I will use getters in this example.

> Instance variables - live for as long as the class lives, they are
>   declared within the body of the class but not within any method or
>   constructor
>
> Method variables - live for as long as the method and no longer, usually
>   do some job and then are gone, they are declared within a
>   method/constructor

```
public class ClassThatWantsFields {

    public String combineFields(ClassWithFields classWithFields){
        //if I have access to the object classWithFields then I have access to its
        //public methods (and possibly also protected and default access; but this is outside the scope of this question)
        return classWithFields.getEnglish()+classWithFields.getFrench();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassWithFields classWithFields=new ClassWithFields();
        ClassThatWantsFields classThatWantsFields=new ClassThatWantsFields();

        System.out.println(classThatWantsFields.combineFields(classWithFields));
    }

}
```

```
public class ClassWithFields {
    private String English; //these are instance variables, they live for as long as the object lives
    private String French;

    private String preservedMayFly; 

    public ClassWithFields(){
        English="A language called English";
        French="A language called French";

        //mayfly is a method variable, it will be gone once the constructor 
        //exits, anything you want to keep for the life of the object should 
        //NOT be a method variable
        String mayfly="I won't live long";

        //preservedMayFly is an instance variable and will live as long as
        //the object
        preservedMayFly=mayfly+"but I can be used within the method"
    }

    public String getEnglish() {
        return English;
    }

    public String getFrench() {
        return French;
    }



}
```